# How do I set the Parameter on a Tableau Dashboard with Python

Tags: python, tableau-api

I need to set parameters to scrape needed data off of:
https://tableau.txdot.gov/views/BidItemAverageCost/BidItemAvgCostDashboard?%3Aembed=y&%3AisGuestRedirectFromVizportal=y

I need to be able to set the Actual Let Date Range and the Bidder Rank, which appear to be parameters. However, nothing comes up when I try to use TableauScraper .getParameters.

I tried setting the parameter even though its not found and its still not working. I need to set the 'Actual Let Date Range' to 12 months and 'Bidder Rank' to Low Bidder.

How can I set the parameter?

```
import requests
from tableauscraper import TableauScraper as TS

init_url = "https://tableau.txdot.gov/views/BidItemAverageCost/BidItemAvgCostDashboard?%3Aembed=y&%3AisGuestRedirectFromVizportal=y"

ts = TS()
ts.loads(init_url)
workbook = ts.getWorkbook()
ws = workbook.getWorksheet("Bid History Avg Cost")


filters=ws.getFilters()
parameters = workbook.getParameters()

three_month_data = workbook.getCrossTabData(sheetName="Bid History Avg Cost")

three_wb = workbook.setParameter("Bidder Rank", "Low Bidder")
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If you know the parameters you want to set the workbook to, you [can pass them through your URL](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/HowTo/how-to-set-workbook-parameter-value-in-view-url-and-in-rest-api-call).